# How to Rewrite/Reorder/Squash svn commit history with git svn?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

This is after `git svn dcommit`:

```
commit5 master git-svn
commit4
commit3
commit2
commit1
```

Now I do `git rebase -i` (using emacs magit but it's the same thing).

I want to squash commit5 with commit3:

```
pick commit1
pick commit2
pick commit3
squash commit5
pick commit4
```

Then once this is done. I get:

```
Recent commits:
commit4
commit3+5
commit2
commit1

Unpulled svn commits:
commit5
commit4
commit3

Unpushed svn commits:
commit4
commit3+5
```

Now if I do `dcommit` or `git svn rebase` both end me in the same situation as before:

```
commit5 master git-svn
commit4
commit3
commit2
commit1
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: May be, because one can not rewrite svn history ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by laurent is right. 
Client side history rewrite is not possible with `svn`, one would require admin rights for this work.